# Create RewriteRule using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to create rule in .htaccess to rewrite from `http://domain/test` to `http://domain/?test` What should I write to .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?$1 [L]
```